# Using mono aot / aot-full compilation: nothing appears to happen?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, aot

I've got a C# project that I need compiled to a native binary.  I've read here:

http://www.mono-project.com/AOT

That Mono can precompile an assembly to one of two options:

1. --aot :  A precompiled image (essentially the same as Ngen as it looks to me)
2. --aot=full:  A fully compiled to native binary instance of the original .exe

I am fairly sure I'm understanding those right, but could be wrong about the --aot=full option.

However, when I run:

```
 mono.exe --aot=full --verbose program.exe
```

I get no output, the last modified date on the executable remains the same, and no files are generated.  I've also tried just as a test:

```
 mono.exe --aot --verbose program.exe
```

I get the same result; no output, no image file or files in general, nothing.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Which platform are you on? And which mono version are you trying?

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge Windows 7 x64, Mono v2.10.6

Answer (score 6):

You should probably make a bug report. AOT info is normally displayed even without --verbose. With --verbose you should get a LOT of prints. Another possibility is that you have broken Mono installation.

Nevertheless if you want to produce native *executable* binary, you should use mkbundle rather than AOT.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want --aot, you want [mkbundle](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications#Bundles).

--aot tells mono to precompile some code rather than use the jit compiler, it does not give you a fully machine-code binary. For this you need mkbundle.

Comment: `mkbundle` does NOT make native code from a .NET binary. it's just a packer. and can be easily reversed.